# How get css files from website?

Tags: html, css, resources

I'm trying to get the content of css files of a website....

```
 <link href="/files/includes/templates-css-main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

For example, it's the link of css ref of http://paceoil.ca/. When I tried to send a request for getting a css file to this url http://paceoil.ca/files/includes/templates-css-main.css, I got an unexpected result.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you expect and what you get instead? Also how does your code you used look like?

Comment: What do you mean "not what you expected"? That second link does contain valid `CSS`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the particular website in question, the reason you're not seeing what you expected is because they've used an uncommon technique called `@import` to load several stylesheets into one. In general, your method is correct -- http://paceoil.ca/files/includes/templates-css-main.css is indeed a link to their stylesheet.

Inside that stylesheet, you'll see the following statements:

```
@import 'templates-css-reset.css';
@import 'templates-css-layout.css';
@import 'templates-css-type.css';
@import 'templates-css-nav.css';
@import 'modules-mod_superfishmenu-tmpl-css-superfish.css';
```

These lines simply load the contents of other `.css` files all together. The other CSS files can be found at:

- http://paceoil.ca/files/includes/templates-css-reset.css
- http://paceoil.ca/files/includes/templates-css-layout.css
- http://paceoil.ca/files/includes/templates-css-type.css
- http://paceoil.ca/files/includes/templates-css-nav.css
- http://paceoil.ca/files/includes/modules-mod_superfishmenu-tmpl-css-superfish.css

It should also be noted that on some websites (most commonly on huge websites like facebook), CSS files are not necessarily statically generated. Some servers run "CSS-preprocessing" which allows them to embed code in CSS that is executed and translated before your browser ever sees it. In cases like this, it is impossible to view that code unless the owner shares it with you.

Answer (score 3):

press F12, resources. then you should see the `css` file of a site